# LyX: раскладка клавиатуры

Tags: клавиатура, latex, lyx

В LyX в **Инструменты>Настройки>Редактирование>Клавиатура/Мышь**, там, где *Клавиатура*, есть флажок *Использовать раскладку клавиатуры*. Никто не знает, зачем он?

Answer (score 4):

Этот неприметный с виду флажок обеспечивает довольно существенный перевес между LyX и другими "настоящими редакторами LaTeX". Я не скажу, что LyX имеет преимущество перед этими редакторами прямо-таки по всем показателям в силу недостаточной своей компетентности в этом вопросе, но с этой стороны он их точно превосходит. Итак, эта функция нужна для того, чтобы с одной клавиатуры (не переключая язык ввода, что, впрочем, пока не важно) можно  было вводить необычные (там, диакритические, и т. п.) символы.
Именно: нажимаем кнопку *Просмотреть* для первой и *Выбрать* для второй клавиатуры (где находятся эти кнопки, указано в первом посте данной темы) и устанавливаем с помощью выбора соответствующих файлов с расширением `.kmap` (на всякий случай скажу, что эти файлы находятся в `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\kbd`), как наи удобно, какой язык (какую раскладку клавиатуры) на какую клавиатуру (первую или вторую) повесить. Нажимаем кнопку *Сохранить* при этом диалоговое окно настроек закроется (в данном случае можно нажать кнопку *Применить*, тогда можно в основном окне LyX что-то делать без ограничения функционала, там, писать, выполнять команды всех меню без закрытия диалогового окна *Настройки*, но мы нажимаем *Сохранить*, потому что нам надо желательно сразу перезапустить LyX). Потом, повторюсь, лучше перезапустить LyX. Язык ввода в окне LyX ставим английский. Переключение раскладок осуществляется сочетаниями клавиш `Alt`+`K`+`1` или `Alt`+`K`+`2` соответственно. Сочетание `Alt`+`K`+`Т` осуществляет переключение между выбранными раскладками по кругу  (так сказано в мануале). Ну, это все мелочи. Хочу, однако, отметить, что в мануале сказано, что эта функция работает не на всех системах. И, действительно, у меня, на Windows 7 максимальной (до этого на профессиональной), это работает (работало) только отчасти: когда в первой указана какая-либо раскладка, переключение на вторую не происходит. Но зато при включении этой функции, независимо от выбранной первой раскладки, при переходе в математический `Ctrl`+`M`) или выклочный (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`M`) режимы, язык ввода становится английским! При выходе же из математического (или выклочного) режима (можно мышкой щелкнуть вне прямоугольника, обозначаемого красными уголками, в котором курсор находится в момент ввода математической формулы, или кнопками навигации курсора) язык ввода становится опять тем, который указан в первой клавиатуре. Это о-очень удобно,  когда пишешь что-то с математическими формулами на языке, отличном от английского: сто раз не переключать язык ввода на английский (для ввода формул) и назад, на свой язык. Однако не для всякого языка в папке, названной мной выше, есть соответствующий файл `.kmap`. Нет его, в частности, для русского языка. Поэтому его нужно изготовить. Делается это довольно просто. Копируем и вставляем в эту же папку файл *null.kmap*, переименовываем его в *russian.kmap* (я подозреваю, что файл *null.kmap* для того и задуман, чтобы непосредственно из него изготавливать нужный пользователю файл `.kmap`, но на всякий случай я его трогать не стал, а изготовил свой). И в *russian.kmap* вставляем такие строки:

```
\kmap q й
\kmap w ц
\kmap e у
..................
\kmap m ь
\kmap "," б
\kmap "." ю
\kmap "6" ‚
\kmap "7" .
\kmap "@" \"
\kmap "^" ;
\kmap "&" : 
\kmap "`" ё
\kmap "~" Ё
\kmap "$" $

\kmap Q Й
\kmap W Ц
\kmap E У
\kmap R К
.............
\kmap L Д
\kmap : Ж
\kmap "”" Э
\kmap Z Я
\kmap X Ч
\kmap C С
\kmap V М
\kmap B И
\kmap N Т
\kmap M Ь
\kmap "<" Б
\kmap ">" Ю
```

т. е. строка имеет такую структуру: «\kmap» «символ английской раскладки» «символ русской раскладки (вернее, казахской раскладки: я ее больше предпочитаю, потому что там наиболее употребительные знаки препинания – точка и запятая – расположены на разных клавишах при практически всех буквах русского языка, нет только букв “Ё” и “ё”, потому что их нет в казахском алфавите, что легко восполнимо с помощью `Alt`-кодов символов), расположенный на одной клавише с введенным ранее английским символом» (наверное, скорее всего, русский символ не обязательно ставить с одной клавиши с кодируемой английской буквой, не пробовал, мне это не к чему). Многоточия обозначают пропущенные буквы. Все, закрываем с сохранением изменений файл *russian.kmap*, который, что перекликается с написанным мной выше, и выбираем для первой раскладки (с помощью кнопки *Просмотреть*, упоминавшейся мной выше), для второй раскладки можно ничего не выбирать. Перезапускаем LyX. Язык ввода ставим английский. При этом он начинает писать русскими буквами так, что какую русскую букву нажмешь, такую он и выведет в окно LyX, при переходе же в математический или выклочный режим (без надоедливого переключения мышкой языка ввода) он выводит в окно LyX латинский символ, который ты и нажимал. ИМХО, очень удобно. Отмечу, что, несмотря на все мои попытки, сделать, чтобы так работала буква "Э", мне не удалось: кавычка вылетает и всё тут. Ну, это и не беда: эта буква употребляется сравнительно редко, так что когда нужно, нажимаем и удерживаем клавишу `Alt`, с цифровой клавиатуры вводим последовательно `1`, `5`, `7`, отпускаем клавишу `Alt`. В окне LyX, там, где мигает курсор, появится буква "Э". На всякий случай выкладываю свой [файл russian.kmap](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17TBYjYK_kbD5giS7DuMnuPXMjd5urVn2). Так, ну, вроде все. Старался писать максимально доходчиво.

Comment: Забыл. Почему-то вместо буквы Э выводит перевернутую кавычку, а маленькую букву э выводит нормально. Но это не критично: опять-таки Alt-коды... Остальные буквы, символы безукоризненно. А все же никто не поможет разобраться с этим косяком?

Comment: L.F.C, вы не совсем верно исправили: перед \kmap не надо тире.

Comment: Ну, я просто привел в читабельный вид. Остальное на тебе. Плюсы тебе поставил за первый вопрос и ответ.  Метку LyX описал. Надеюсь продолжишь. Удачи! :)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Обязательно продолжу.