# Автоматизация в программе LyX с помощью файлов .js

Tags: lyx

Вот при наборе текста в программе LyX руки можно вообще не отрывать от клавиатуры. Однако для вставки графики приходится-таки использовать мышку. Это доставляет некоторое неудобство. А никто не знает, можно ли упростить эту процедуру? Ведь в файлах `.js`  имеется возможность имитации нажатия клавиш. А это представляется мне довольно мощным средством.

Answer (score 0):

Это соображение показалось мне довольно вкусным. Я начал копать в эту сторону. И хочу поделиться этими находками. Итак. Основной, ИМХО, особенностью файлов с расширением `.js`, делающей их интересными в плане применения их в программе LyX, является, повторюсь, возможность имитации в этих файлах нажатий клавиш. Именно, рассмотрим, например, как можно сделать так, чтобы в редактируемый в настоящий момент файл .lyx можно было вставлять фото, находящееся в одной папке с этим файлом .lyx (если этот файл еще не сохранен, его окно открыто через **Файл>Создать**, ну, его окно открыто в первый раз буквально при использовании прогры LyX в этот раз, то вставляемое фото должно находиться в папке, указанной в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Пути**, в текстовом поле *Каталог пользователя*) без использования мышки, не отрывая рук от клавы. Основной идеей в решении этой проблемы является следующее. Допустим, в папке, о которой я говорил выше, имеется фото *photo.png*. Чтобы его вставить в текущее положение курсора в окне программы LyX, можно выполнить в [Буфере команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066002/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-lyx-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B) следующую команду:

```
inset-apply graphics filename photo.png
```

Таким образом, в файле `.js`, назовем его *vstavka-grafiki.js*, нужно будет сымитировать нажатие сочетания клавиш `Alt`+`X` (для того, чтобы курсор начал мигать в буфере команды) и нажатие клавиш `i`, `n`, `s`, `e`, `t`, `-`, `a`, `p`, `p`, `l`, `y`, `Пробел`, `g`, `r`, `a`, `p`, `h`, `i`, `c`, `s`, `Пробел`, `f`, `i`, `l`, `e`, `n`, `a`, `m`, `e`, `Пробел`. После этого окно программы LyX начинает выглядеть следующим образом:

[image]

При этом, если я сейчас начну что-то вводить с клавы, то это будет вводиться не в основное окно прогры LyX, а в буфер команды, да к тому же буквы будут вводиться с нажимаемых клавиш не те, которые вводятся при нажатии этих клавиш при русской раскладке, а те, которые вводятся при нажатии этих клавиш, когда раскладка клавы переключена на английскую. Отлично, то, что нужно! Но тут, как выяснилось впоследствии, есть одна загвоздка, а именно: сначала я думал прикрутить этот файл .js к прогре LyX через файл [default.def](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066226/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-default-def-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5-lyx), вписав в него строку

```
\define "vstgr" "vc-command U \"$$p\" \"vstavka-grafiki.js\""
```

и, [создав в программе LyX горячую клавишу на словосочетание *call vstgr*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978064/lyx-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8). Все бы хорошо, но выяснилось, что из программы LyX файлы `.js` запускать не получается. Зато из нее получается запускать файлы с расширением `.bat` (банальные батники). Именно поэтому я в файле `default.def` написал

```
\define "vstgr" "vc-command U \"$$p\" \"vstavka-grafiki.bat\""
```

сделав файл vstavka-grafiki.bat следующего содержания:

```
start vstavka-grafiki.js
```

А непосредственно для упрощения вызова созданной мной команды в окне LyX я, как и задумывал, когда еще не знал, что потребуется использовать еще и батник, создал горячую клавишу на словосочетание *call vstgr*. При этом и файл *vstavka-grafiki.bat*, и файл *vstavka-grafiki.js * должны находиться в папке, добавленной в РАТН. Так, идем дальше. [При создании формата экспорта pdflatex-v-papke](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067333/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5-lyx-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-bat) я столкнулся вот с чем. При вставке графики, например, с упомянутым выше именем с расширением *photo.png* в части окна прогры LyX, появляющейся после нажатия **Вид>View Source** (или **Вид>Просмотреть код** - название соответствующего пункта меню Вид зависит от используемого [файла локализации `.mo`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064164/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-lyx-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC) на месте, соответствующем положению вставленной графики в основном окне программы LyX, будет следующий код:

```
\includegraphics{photo}
```

И этот же код будет записан в соответствующий файл `.tex`, появляющийся в соответствующем временном каталоге в результате действия батника, выбранного в качестве движка этого формата на одном из самых первых этапов работы этого батника. Как следствие, в результате выполнения одной из последующих команд этого батника - обработки полученного файла `.tex` - возникнет ошибка и ничего не получится. А проблема здесь в том, что в образующийся файл `.tex` имя вставляемого графического файла (аргумент команды `\includegraphics`) записывается без расширения. Что же делать? Хм, ведь помимо получения файла `.tex`, обработка которого pdflatex'ом не вызывала бы ни одной ошибки, хотелось бы еще сохранить и наглядность в окне программы LyX. С другой стороны, при вставке графики в окно программы LyX в нашем, русскоязычном случае, символы, вставляемые при нажатии клавиш клавы, будут, скорее всего, кириллическими, в то время, как расширения файлов вообще, в частности, графических, записываются английскими. С другой стороны, читатель, дочитавший этот блог до этого места, уже, скорее всего, знает про весьма вкусную функцию прогры LyX - [*Использовать раскладку клавиатуры*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956589/lyx-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B?rq=1) и вовсю ее использует. Что ж, если это так, то задача значительно упрощается. Именно, вот мы открыли файл в программе LyX, переключили раскладку на английскую, а писать мы начали, нажимая буквы, которые нам нужно, так, как будто раскладка поставлена на русскую, символы, которые вводятся в окно программы LyX, - это кириллические символы, расположенные на нажимаемых клавишах. Тут все ОК. Вот мы писали, писали, хоп, нам понадобилось вставить графику. До этого момента вводились кириллические символы, а сейчас нам стало нужным вводить буквы английские (для ввода расширения). Так мы просто-напросто возьмем и перейдем в математический режим, в котором и напишем имя вставляемого фото вместе с его расширением, после этого запустим специально для этого созданной нами горячей клавишей (у меня это `Ctrl`+`0 с цифрового блока клавиатуры`+`V`+`G` (потому что *вставка графики*)) специально определенную в файле *default.def* команду *vstgr1*. Определена эта команда так:

```
\define "vstgr1" "vc-command U \"$$p\" \"vstavka-grafiki1.bat\""
```

(а предыдущая горячая клавиша назначена на словосочетание *call vstgr1*). Как нетрудно догадаться, эта команда запускает батник *vstavka-grafiki1.bat* следующего содержания:

```
start vstavka-grafiki1.js
```

Как нетрудно догадаться, этот батник запускает файл *vstavka-grafiki1.js*, который, по существу, все и делает. Что же он делает? Давайте сначала я опишу, какую конструкцию мы хотим получить в редактируемом в настоящий момент файле `.lyx`. Мы хотим, чтобы там с новой строки (если мы там до этого уже что-то написали, если нет, так и не надо новой строки, см. ниже) было вставлено нужное нам фото, потом, опять с новой строки, был бы вставлен блок кода ТеХ (то, что обычно появляется в окне программы LyX при нажатии сочетания клавиш `Ctrl`+`L`) и в этом блоке было бы написано

```
\includegraphics{}
```

, где в фигурных скобках стояло бы имя вставляемого фото, потом точка, потом расширение вставляемого фото. По сути, мы делаем, чтобы в окне программы LyX вставляемое фото отображалось только для декорации в окне программы LyX, нам не нужно, чтобы в окончательном `.pdf` отображалось это фото: в окончательном `.pdf` будет отображаться фото, которое там появится в результате выполнения команды, стоящей в блоке TeX, поэтому, чтобы предотвратить появления в конечном `.pdf` графики, возникающей в результате обработки наглядной графики из окна прогры LyX, мы эту наглядную графику в этом окне прогры LyX закомментируем, ставя перед этой наглядной графики знак процента, вставленный в блок кода TeX. Одним словом, мы хотим получить, например, следующую конструкцию:

[image]

Я принципиально делаю все то же самое, что и в первом случае: точно так же прикручиваю файл *vstavka-grafiki1.bat* к LyX'у через файл *default.def*, создавая в этом файле новую команду *vstgr1*, а потом создаю в окне программы LyX горячую клавишу на словосочетание *call vstgr1*, это все понятно. Отличие будет только в файле *vstavka-grafiki1.js*, который запускается файлом *vstavka-grafiki1.bat*. Перед тем, как приводить содержание файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js*, я приведу содержание двух вспомогательных файлов, использующихся в этом файле. А именно, чтобы это все сделать, нам бы потребовалось в том числе в файле *vstavka-grafiki1.js* сымитировать нажатие знака процента. А, т. к. используется казахская раскладка клавы (я использую казахскую раскладку клавиатуры, потому и пишу, исходя из того, что мой читатель тоже ее использует) и, т. к. при такой раскладке клавиатуры символ, вводимый, к примеру, в блокнот, при нажатии клавиши, на которой расположен этот знак процента, является буквой казахского алфавита, то и в команде, имитирующей нажатие знака процента файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js*, нам нужно было бы писать эту казахскую букву, что, как я писал здесь в каком-то другом посте серии постов про программу LyX, вызывает ошибку. Поэтому в файле vstavka-grafiki1.js используется батник procent.bat следующего содержания:

```
echo LYXCMD:vvod:command-sequence:self-insert %%> \\.\pipe\lyxpipe.in
```

Вспоминая [вот это повествование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066881/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-lyx), нетрудно понять, что этот батник действительно вставляет знак процента в текущее в прогре LyX положение курсора (естественно, чтобы этим возможно было пользоваться, в **Инструменты>Настройки...>Пути** в текстовом поле *Канал сервера LyX:* должно стоять *\.\pipe\lyxpipe*, а при попытке использования файла *procent.bat* в применении к LyX вне файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js* необходимо соблюдать нужный порядок запуска окна командной строки, из которого будет вызываться файл *vstavka-grafiki1.js* и окна прогры LyX, в которое этот самый знак процента будет вставляться. За подробностями я отсылаю читателя к посту по последней приведенной ссылке. Впрочем, при вызове *procent.bat* из *vstavka-grafiki1.js* все проходит, как надо). Другим вспомогательным файлом, использующемся в файле *vstavka-grafiki1.js*, является файл *Ostanovka.js* следующего содержания:

```
WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Popup("Если до сих пор все шло правильно, нажмите кнопку \"Ок\", иначе \"Отмена\"", 0, "Контроль процесса",1);
```

А ето шо за чудо-юдо? Дело в том, что, когда я создавал файл *vstavka-grafiki1.js* выполняющемся без остановок, во время его работы, видимо, в том числе и из-за запуска из него других файлов с командами, которые должны выполниться в том же окне прогры LyX, в котором файл *vstavka-grafiki1.js* сам выполняет команды, в разных местах возникали ошибки, эти команды файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js* в своей совокупности делали не то, что надо. Чтобы это устранить, я придумал вот что. Экспериментально выявлял такие места в файле *vstavka-grafiki1.js*. Именно, команды в этом файле, вызывающие ошибки. И перед этими местами я хотел приостанавливать работу файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js* до нажатия мной какой-нибудь клавиши. Какой - еще не знал. Думал я думал и вспомнил, что у команды-не команды, неважно, в общем, у *WshShell.Run(* есть такой аргумент, что, если его значение указать как *true*, то при выполнении этой команды работа основного, из которого эта команда выполняется, файла приостанавливается ровно до тех пор, пока не закроется открытый этой командой файл. Что ж, уже кое-что... С другой стороны, я вспомнил, что в jscript есть команда, открывающая диалоговое окно с реально функционирующими кнопками. Сложив все это вместе, я решил перед проблемными местами файла vstavka-grafiki1.js вставлять команду запуска файла Ostanovka.js с параметром ожидания окончания работы этого файла. Файл же Ostanovka.js будет создавать диалоговое окно с двумя кнопками - Ок и Отмена, при этом после выплывания этого окна фокус будет находиться на кнопке Ok, так что, чтобы закрыть это диалоговое окно, достаточно будет нажать клавишу `Enter`. Итак, файл Ostanovka.js мы сделаем приведенного мной выше содержания. Я хотел еще на кнопку Отмена навесить еще отмену всех действий, выполненных файлом vstavka-grafiki1.j после последнего запуска файла Ostanovka.js, да пока не знаю, как это сделать. Спросил на форуме, там сказали, ищите сами Гуглом, а я не знаю, что написать в поиске. Короче, если там помогут, я приведу обновленное содержание файла *Ostanovka.js*, а пока будем довольствоваться тем, что мне удалось наклепать. Так, ну, все, после сделанных предварительных замечаний читатель в состоянии понять процесс работы файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js*. Я буду в комментарии к каждой строке писать, что она выполняет. Не забываем, что перед началом работы файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js* курсор в окне прогры LyX находится в математическом режиме, после имени вставляемого графического файла, точки, отделяющей его имя от расширения и самого расширения. Итак, вот файл *vstavka-grafiki1.js*:

```
WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.SendKeys("%лч"); 
WshShell.SendKeys("+{HOME}"); //выделяем находящееся в мат. режим имя 
//вставляемой графики, отделенное точкой от его расширения 
WshShell.SendKeys("^с"); //копируем выделение, сделанное на предыдущем шаге 
WshShell.SendKeys("{LEFT}"); //выводим курсор влево из мат. режиме, 
 //про который я писал в комменте к третьей строке 
WshShell.SendKeys("{END}"); //помещаю курсор в положение после 
//мат. режима, про который я писал в комменте к третьей строке 
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}"); //начинаю новую строку под мат. режимом,  
//про который я писал в комменте к третьей строке
WshShell.Run("Ostanovka.js",1,true); //приостанавливаю работу файла 
//vstavka-grafiki1.js
WshShell.SendKeys("^д"); //вставляю блок TeX 
WshShell.SendKeys("^д"); //вставляю блок TeX
WshShell.Run("Ostanovka.js",1,true); //приостанавливаю работу файла 
WshShell.Run("Ostanovka.js",1,true); //приостанавливаю работу файла
//vstavka-grafiki1.js
WshShell.Run("procent.bat"); //вставляю знак процента во вставленный ранее блок TeX 
WshShell.Run("Ostanovka.js",1,true); //приостанавливаю работу файла 
//vstavka-grafiki1.js
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}"); //выхожу вправо из уже содержащего знак 
//процента блока TeX 
WshShell.SendKeys("%ч"); //перехожу в Буфер команды
WshShell.SendKeys("штыуе-фзздн пкфзршсы ашдутфьу "); //после выполнения 
//этой команды в буфере команды оказывается написано
//inset-apply graphics filename с пробелом после слова filename 
WshShell.SendKeys("^м"); // вставляю в буфер команды из буфера памяти 
//компа скопированное ранее имя вставляемой графики вместе с его расширением, 
//отделенным точкой от имени
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}"); //имитирую нажатие клавиши ENTER, при 
//этом после выполнения этой команды в основном
//окне прогры LyX становится видимо вставляемое фото
//WshShell.SendKeys("{UP}"); //перевожу курсор в основном окне прогры LyX 
//в строку, где стоит имя вставляемого фото вместе с его расширением, 
//находящиеся в мат. режиме, при этом курсор мигает в самом конце этой строки, 
//вне этого мат. режима

WshShell.SendKeys("{LEFT}"); //ввод курсора в мат. режим, про который я 
//писал в комменте к предыдущему шагу
WshShell.SendKeys("+{HOME}"); //выделение имени вставляемого фото, 
//вместе с его расширением, отделенным точкой от его имени
WshShell.SendKeys("^ч"); //вырезание выделения, сделанного на предыдущем шаге 
WshShell.SendKeys("^ч"); //вырезание выделения, сделанного на предыдущем шаге
WshShell.SendKeys("{LEFT}"); //выход влево из опустевшего математического режима 
WshShell.SendKeys("{DELETE}"); //удаление ставшего пустым после 
//вырезания имени вставляемого фото вместе с его расширением, отделенным
//точкой от его имени, математического режима 
WshShell.SendKeys("{DELETE}"); //удаление опустевшей после удаления 
//предыдущим шагом строки
WshShell.SendKeys("{END}"); //после выполнения предыдущей команды курсор 
//перед выполнением этой команды мигает перед знаком процента, находящемся в блоке 
//ТеХ. Так вот, после выполнения этой команды курсор оказывается 
//мигающим в конце этой строки, после ставшей до этого отображаться 
//в окне прогры LyX вставляемого фотки
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}"); //Начало новой строки 
WshShell.SendKeys("^д"); //вставка в начатую предыдущей командой новую строку 
//блока ТеХ
WshShell.SendKeys("\штсдгвупкфзршсы"); //вписывание в блок ТеХ, созданный предыдущей 
//командой, \includegraphics
WshShell.SendKeys("+х"); //дальше вписываем в этот блок ТеХ открывающую 
//фигурную скобку
WshShell.SendKeys("^м"); //вставляем в этот блок ТеХ скопированное ранее имя 
//вставляемой графики вместе с его расширением,
//отделенным точкой от его имени
WshShell.SendKeys("+ъ"); //дальше вписываем в этот блок ТеХ закрывающую 
//фигурную скобку
WshShell.SendKeys("{RIGHT}"); //выводим курсор вправо из блока ТеХ
```

Скажу еще пару слов по поводу приведенного кода. Во-первых, комментарии в jscript обозначаются знаком `//` и все, что стоит в строке после этого знака, игнорируется выполнителем этого кода, оно предназначено для объяснения человеку действий, выполняемых этой строкой. А если в строке ничего перед `//` нет, то эта строка продолжает комментарий, начатый где-то выше. Во-вторых, я в первый раз скопировал имя вставляемого фото вместе с его расширением, отделенным точкой от его имени, а во второй раз вырезал эту конструкцию вместо кажущегося возможным ее вырезанием один раз. Почему? Да потому что, когда я так пытался сделать, перед вставкой в текущее положение этой конструкции из буфера обмена во второй раз, он загадочным образом становился пуст и у меня ничего не выходило. Почему так происходит, я объяснить не могу, однако, я нашел такой выход из возникшей проблемы. Еще раз хочу напомнить, что в процессе работы файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js* при появлении диалогового окна с заголовком Контроль процесса для продолжения работы файла *vstavka-grafiki1.js* нужно нажать клавишу `Enter` (или левой кнопкой мышки нажать какую-нибудь кнопку в выплывшем диалоговом окне, что представляется мне менее удобным).