# Не вводится большая буква "э" в программе LyX

Tags: lyx

Вот, когда в программе LyX, используемой в том виде, в котором ее создали, нажимаешь сочетание Shift+Э (это я говорю про тот случай, когда при включенной функции [Использовать раскладку клавиатуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/956589/lyx-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B) раскладка клавы переключена на английскую), вместо появления ожидаемой большой буквы "Э", в окне прогры LyX появляется перевернутая верхняя кавычка. Никто не знает, как это исправить? Вроде, и программа мощная, что они там намудрили с кириллицей? Короче, Сталин прав: кругом враги). Намудрили енти англосаксы с русишом.

Answer (score 0):

Я долго не мог придумать, как устранить этот косячок. На идею его обхода меня натолкнула [вот эта страница](https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/CommandSequences). Решением этой проблемы является [назначение горячей клавиши](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/978064/lyx-%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8) Shift+" на словосочетание *command-sequence self-insert Э*.